# Oracle aggregate functions and how to concatenate all values in column

Tags: sql, oracle, max, concatenation, aggregate

All,

My Oracle Database is version 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit

I have the following statement which usefully gets me the max (or min or count etc) values in each case as expected however what I would like is to get and to concatenate all of the values rather than the max, min or count - is there an elegant way to do this please ?

```
SELECT lla.id, 
       max(decode(lla.attrid, 2, lla.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 2",
       min(decode(lla.attrid, 3, lla.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 3",
       count(decode(lla2.attrid, 5, lla2.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 5"
FROM llattrdata lla, llattrdata lla2
WHERE lla.id = lla2.id 
      AND lla.defid = 111111 --category id 1
      AND lla2.defid = 222222 --category id 2
      AND lla.id = 48212327 and lla2.id = 48212327
      GROUP BY lla.id
```

Hoping for a row that looks something like this:

```
12121212 | fred, jack, gill | 56 | 29,10
```

To be clearer it is the values that the 'Attribute Name 3' (for example) contains that I want to see all of and not just the max or the minimum. In other words for that attribute I can get the max or the min value or even the count but cannot see a way to get all of the values ?  In other words I can get 10 as the min and 29 as the max - even 2 as the count but not 29 and 10 in the same column !

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: why all these backticks?

Comment: use `||` for concatenation. e.g. `SELECT 'conca' || 'tenation' FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.department_id,
       listagg(e.first_name) within group (order by e.department_id) "Attribute Name 2"
FROM employees e join
     departments d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id 
GROUP BY e.department_id;
```

you can use above example and alter your query

Comment: Thank you for the answers but unless I am mistaken the LISTAGG analytic function was introduced in Oracle 11g Release 2.

Comment: Seems **LISTAGG** was in Oracle 10 as non-documented.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wmsys.wm_concat` function [learn more here](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm) about it. This is a non-documented function in Oracle 10.

It returns you comma-separated list, you can use `replace` function to replace comma with the thing you need.

Unfortunately this function does not have `order` clause so you cannot specify the order in the list.

**EDIT:**

As far as this function is not available for you, you can simply create it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE wm_concat_impl
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS OBJECT (
   curr_str   VARCHAR2 (32767),
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY wm_concat_impl
IS
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      sctx := wm_concat_impl (NULL);
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         curr_str := curr_str || ',' || p1;
      ELSE
         curr_str := p1;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      returnvalue := curr_str;
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (sctx2.curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         SELF.curr_str := SELF.curr_str || ',' || sctx2.curr_str;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wm_concat (p1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AGGREGATE USING wm_concat_impl;
/
```

The query is taken from [this website](http://www.sql.ru/forum/531677/wmsys-wm-concat-v-xe), it is, unfortunately, in Russian, but just use this custom aggregate function for your purposes.

Comment: Simon - this is certainly on the right track (despite my poor explanation - now updated a little !) but it seems that this undocumented function is not available - it there a way to enable it that I am missing ?

Comment: Simon - I really appreciate the perseverance and now have the custom aggregate function in place.  Of course as is all too often the case I now get an 'ORA-00937: not a single-group group function' after adding the call ', max(decode(lla.attrid, 20, wm_concat(lla.valstr), null)) "concat_attrs"'...

Comment: yes, because you use one analytic function inside of another one. Try to run e.g. `select max(count(*)) from dual`, I am not sure it will work. You can make a subquery to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT lla.id || ' | ' ||
       max(decode(lla.attrid, 2, lla.valstr, null)) || ' | ' ||
       min(decode(lla.attrid, 3, lla.valstr, null)) || ' | ' ||
       count(decode(lla2.attrid, 5, lla2.valstr, null))
FROM llattrdata lla, llattrdata lla2
WHERE lla.id = lla2.id 
      AND lla.defid = 111111 --category id 1
      AND lla2.defid = 222222 --category id 2
      AND lla.id = 48212327 and lla2.id = 48212327
      GROUP BY lla.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I have added some more to the question as I suspect that in re-reading my post it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the STRAGG ( as in STRing AGGregate) function created by Tom Kyte.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336

```
create or replace type stragg_type as object
(
  string varchar2(4000),
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize
    ( sctx in out stragg_type )
    return number ,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate
    ( self  in out stragg_type ,
      value in     varchar2
    ) return number ,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate
    ( self        in  stragg_type,
      returnvalue out varchar2,
      flags in number
    ) return number ,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge
    ( self in out stragg_type,
      ctx2 in     stragg_type
    ) return number
);
/

create or replace type body stragg_type
is
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( sctx in out stragg_type )
  return number
  is
  begin
    sctx := stragg_type( null ) ;
    return ODCIConst.Success ;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  in out stragg_type ,
    value in     varchar2
  ) return number
  is
  begin
    self.string := self.string || ',' || value ;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self        in  stragg_type ,
    returnvalue out varchar2 ,
    flags       in  number
  ) return number
  is
  begin
    returnValue := ltrim( self.string, ',' );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge
  ( self in out stragg_type ,
    ctx2 in     stragg_type
  ) return number
  is
  begin
    self.string := self.string || ctx2.string;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace function stragg
  ( input varchar2 )
  return varchar2
  deterministic
  parallel_enable
  aggregate using stragg_type
;
/
```

Run the three create statements one after the other in sqlplus or sqldev. Now the stragg() function is created in your user schema. Then you can do:

```
SELECT lla.id, 
       max(decode(lla.attrid, 2, lla.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 2",
       STRAGG(decode(lla.attrid, 3, lla.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 3 List",
       count(decode(lla2.attrid, 5, lla2.valstr, null)) "Attribute Name 5"
FROM llattrdata lla, llattrdata lla2
WHERE lla.id = lla2.id 
      AND lla.defid = 111111 --category id 1
      AND lla2.defid = 222222 --category id 2
      AND lla.id = 48212327 and lla2.id = 48212327
GROUP BY lla.id
```